# Sharepoint: Cannot add a new app catalogue

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I am trying to add a new app catalogue site to Sharepoint. However, I cannot add anything in the field "Administrator". When trying to add a user there is nobody listed even though I am a global admin.

The screenshots are in German but I hope you get the idea:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

ok I typed my name into the "Administrator" field and submitted the form, somehow magically I was set as admin and the app catalogue page was created - which is what I wanted.

I still don't get though why this is such an awkward and non-intuitive process. Why does my name not shop up in the "Personen auswählen (select person)" dialog?!?

Comment: there was probably some javascript error in your browser console